# Best way to write in remote database

Tags: mysql

I have a website on server 1 that is using a database (MySQL) on the same server.

I have a web-application on server 2 that is using an other database (MySQL too) on the same server

Both MySQL are limited with local access only

I want my web-application to update few data in the MySQL database of server 1 (so that it is reflected on my website).

What is the best way?

- Grant MySQL access on server 1 for user from another server than localhost
- Send a HTTP request to a php script on server 1, this will then do the database update

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do it is use web service to communicate between two application on different server . you can user SOAP or REST web service .